# Appending an element to associative array awk

Tags: awk, associative-array

I've got an input file (input.txt) with a few fields:

```
A1  B1  C1  D1  E1
A2  B2  C2  D1  E2
A3  B3  C3  D2  E3
A4  B4  C4  D2  E4
```

And I want to append elements of an associative array,

```
awk '{a[$4]=a[$4] $5; print a[$4]} END {for(b in a) {print a[b]}}' input.txt
```

I think the output should be (ie E2 is concatenated to E1, and E4 is concatenated to E3):

```
E1 E2
E3 E4
```

but instead the output is:

```
E2
E4
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the end goal - what is the AWK script supposed to do - what is the correct output supposed to be?

Comment: I've made some assumptions about your intent in my updated answer. Please clarify by updating your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output isn't consistent with your command, but I assume that you want the following:

- build up a list of 5th-column values for each unique 4th-column value
- print these lists, preceded by the respective 4th-column value

A naïve fix to get what you want would be:

```
$ awk '{a[$4]=a[$4] " " $5} END {for (b in a) { print b; print a[b]}}' input.txt
D1
 E1 E2
D2
 E3 E4
```

but there are two things to note:

- The accumulated 5-th column values will have a leading space - which happens to help with grouped output in this case.
- Due to enumerating the keys with `for (b in a)`, the 4th-column values will NOT appear in the order they appear in the input, because the order in which `awk` enumerates keys of its [always associative] arrays is based on internal hash values, which has no guaranteed relationship to the order in which array elements were *added* (nor does it guarantee any particular order in general).