# print column with unique value

Tags: awk, sed

I have 2 columns in a text file. I want to print all distinct value associated with a duplicate column.

```
VZTFARATGJBBCEGIM01 RGROUP-GIMAGES
VZTFARATGJBFFEGIM01 RGROUP-GIMAGES
VZTFARATGJBSTEGIM01 RGROUP-GIMAGES
VZTFARATGJBBCE024701 RGROUP-ENV0247
VZTFARATGJBFFE024701 RGROUP-ENV0247
VZTFARATGJBSTE024701 RGROUP-ENV0247
VZTFARATGOD11E024701 RGROUP-ENV0247
```

```
GROUP-ENV0247
VZTFARATGJBBCE024701
VZTFARATGJBFFE024701
VZTFARATGJBSTE024701
VZTFARATGOD11E024701

GROUP-GIMAGES
VZTFARATGAWSTEGIM01
VZTFARATGENTFEGIM01
VZTFARATGJBBCEGIM01
VZTFARATGJBFFEGIM01
```

Comment: Is this only going to be done using awk or command line as well?

Comment: any solution will be workable. Sorry for type file contain 2 column

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Vijay Verma I updated my answer to use awk only with the output you desired, also I added an explanation of what it is doing.

Comment: @Cyrus looks like the solution is similar to this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179431/appending-an-element-to-associative-array-awk

Comment: Seven input records produced eight output records. Also, what do you mean by _unique value_? The sample didn't address that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution in awk.

```
awk -F'[ ]' '{ b[$2]=b[$2]  $1 "\n" } END { for (c in b) { print c; print b[c] }}' test.txt
```

Where test.txt contained the values:

```
VZTFARATGJBBCEGIM01 RGROUP-GIMAGES 
VZTFARATGJBFFEGIM01 RGROUP-GIMAGES 
VZTFARATGJBSTEGIM01 RGROUP-GIMAGES 
VZTFARATGJBBCE024701 RGROUP-ENV0247 
VZTFARATGJBFFE024701 RGROUP-ENV0247 
VZTFARATGJBSTE024701 RGROUP-ENV0247 
VZTFARATGOD11E024701 RGROUP-ENV0247
```

And the output looks like:

```
RGROUP-ENV0247
VZTFARATGJBBCE024701
VZTFARATGJBFFE024701
VZTFARATGJBSTE024701
VZTFARATGOD11E024701

RGROUP-GIMAGES
VZTFARATGJBBCEGIM01
VZTFARATGJBFFEGIM01
VZTFARATGJBSTEGIM01
```

And how it works:

```
awk -F'[ ]'   // deliminate on empty space
'{ 
    // add value to associated array and append with newline
    b[$2]=b[$2]  $1 "\n"
} 
END { 
  // print out each 'key', and their respective values
  for (c in b) { 
    print c; print b[c] 
  }
}' 
test.txt      // file to read from
```

Comment: If it works for you, you can upvote it here. Also in future please avoid modifying answers unless they add to the provided solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk and 2D arrays to weed out the duplicates in `$1`:

```
$ awk '{
    a[$2][$1]           # hash to a. This weeds out duplicates in $1
}
END {
    for(i in a) {       # all groups
        print i         # output name
        for(j in a[i])  # all group members
            print j     # output member
        print ""        # empty line after each group
    }
}' file
```

Output:

```
RGROUP-ENV0247
VZTFARATGOD11E024701
VZTFARATGJBSTE024701
VZTFARATGJBBCE024701
VZTFARATGJBFFE024701

RGROUP-GIMAGES
VZTFARATGJBBCEGIM01
VZTFARATGJBSTEGIM01
VZTFARATGJBFFEGIM01
```

Another for non-GNU awks. Using `match` to test if there are duplicates in `a[$2]`:

```
$ awk '
{
    if(!match(a[$2],"(^|\n)" $1 "($|\n)"))
    a[$2]=a[$2] "\n" $1
}
END {
    for(i in a) {
        print i a[i]
        print ""
    }
}
```

There will be an extra empty line in the end.

Comment: Nice answer, didn't know about the [$2][$1] to help with uniqueness. Going to upvote yours over mine :D